# python - zip (skip over an element from one list but not from other)

Tags: python

I've 2 list, `a` and `b`. Lets say `len(a)` = `len(b) + 1`. I want to iterate over both the list simultaneously, with a condition. Since, `a` has extra garbage value, it should skip that value from `a`, but it shouldnt skip the value from `b`. Then when next iteration  happen, `a` should start from next element and `b` front the same initial element.

Explaination in the example.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,19,20]
b = [7,8,9,10,11,17,18]

for x,y in zip(a,b):
    if x == 5: # some condition
        #in this case y is 11
        continue # skip the value 5 from a but dont skip 11 from b.
    print x,y
```

The expected output will be

```
1 7
2 8
3 9
4 10
6 11 # 5 skipped because of some condition, but 11 remains intact
19 17
20 18
```

How can I do it?

**OR** if theres any other solution,while iterating simultaneously, please let me know.

Comment: can you show the expected output ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know which value you want to skip until you're already in the loop, you can use iterators, and call `next` to discard a value:

```
import itertools

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,19,20]
b = [7,8,9,10,11,17,18]

it_a = iter(a)
it_b = iter(b)

for x,y in itertools.izip(it_a, it_b):
    if x == 5:
        x = next(it_a)
    print x,y
```

Which gives:

```
1 7
2 8
3 9
4 10
6 11
19 17
20 18
```

Be careful, though. If you call `next(it_a)`, and you've read all of the values from `a`'s iterator, you'll get a `StopIteration` exception, and you'll probably want to handle that somehow. Also, note that if you somehow skip *two* elements of `a`, then `a` will run out of elements before `b`, and `zip` will silently stop before producing the last element of `b`.

Alternatively, if you *do* know what you'd like to exclude before entering the `for`-loop, you can do essentially what @wnnmaw suggests below, but with a generator comprehension rather than a list comprehension. This will do the exclusion lazily:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,19,20]
b = [7,8,9,10,11,17,18]

it_a = (x for x in a if x not in {5, 42, 101})

for x,y in zip(it_a, b):
    print x,y
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do this is to simply cut out the "garbage" before zipping

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,19,20]
>>> b = [7,8,9,10,11,17,18]
>>> a.remove(5)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 19, 20]
>>> zip(a,b)
[(1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9), (4, 10), (6, 11), (19, 17), (20, 18)]
>>>
```

If your condition is more complicated than just one value, you could do something like this:

```
>>> a = (i for i in a if not i in list_of_excluded_values)
```

Finally, as sweeneyrod points out in the comments, you can take a copy of `a` before you remove garbage with `a_trimmed = a[:]`

Comment: If required, you could copy the list before deleting it so it isn't changed.

Comment: I thought of this as well, but to do that, I first need to find the index of 5 and then remove it, which might turn out costly!!!

Comment: @user1162512, ```list.remove(x)``` removes the list element with the value of ```x```, so you don't need to find the index

Comment: I know, but the example that I provided was just dummy, what if according to some condition, the garbage value turns out to be at 9th index/4th index/100th index and so on. I first have to iterate over the list to find the index of the garbage value and then remove it and then perform `zip` operation. This might turn out costly, ie `first iterating to find the index of garbage value, and then removing it and then zip`. Thats why I turned down this solution, I initiallly thought.

Comment: @user1162512 You could make that list comprehension into a generator comprehension, and that would do the exclusion lazily.

Comment: Any better way to go ??

Comment: @user1162512, I understand now, if performance is that big of a concern then you should be using iterators as in jme's answer

Comment: @wnnmaw Your solution is just as efficient (as long as it's known what values should be excluded before entering the `for`-loop): Just make that list comprehension a generator comprehension. I've mentioned as much in my post, but if you make the change in yours I'll happily delete that bit so as not to encroach on your answer.

Comment: @jme, no need to delete your answer, I quite like it, its very clever